# Java reflection - Error throw

Tags: java, exception, reflection, throws

I have the following code:

```
class ClassDetails {
  private String current_class;
  public ClassDetails(String current_class) {
    this.current_class = current_class;
  }
  public void getClassDetails() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        Class theClass = Class.forName(current_class);
        String name = theClass.getName() ;
        System.out.println(name);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}

class MMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ClassDetails C = new ClassDetails(args[0]);
      C.getClassDetails();
  }
}
```

And I have this error in main:

```
Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Well you've probably provided the wrong name when running the code... unfortunately, as we don't know what you've run, or what class you're trying to load, it's hard to give any more advice...

Comment: I'm not running it. I can't because I have that error.

Comment: @JonSkeet This is a compile-time error, see my post.

Comment: @MrLore: Doh, saw the ClassNotFoundException and misread the rest :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `main` method calls the `getClassDetails()` method, which throws that exception, as the signature shows:

```
public void getClassDetails() throws ClassNotFoundException
```

And you aren't catching it, or throwing it in the method, so your code will not compile. So you must either do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ClassDetails C = new ClassDetails(args[0]);
    C.getClassDetails();
}
```

Or:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassDetails C = new ClassDetails(args[0]);
      try
      {
          C.getClassDetails();
      }
      catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
      {
          //Add exception handling here
      }
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively, as the method *is* catching the exception, get rid of it from the throws clause.